# EmailComposer Cordova no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova

Estava lendo um projeto no gitHub de plugin de email do cordova e não entendi como instala.
Ele te dá a opção para baixar os arquivos, e depois pede para que você coloque essa linha no xml.

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" />
```

Só que depois, o que tenho que fazer? colocar o composer.js dentro da pasta de arquivos de js? e as pastas dos dispositivos android, ios e w8, onde vão?
Alguém pode me ajudar ?
A fonte vem daqui: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer#open-a-pre-filled-email-draft

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você tem que instalá-lo, da forma como os plugins são instalados por padrão no cordova:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git
```

Em seguida você verifica no seu código se o cordova está habilitado (para não dar erro quando você for visualizar no browser do pc).

E então você utiliza os métodos isAvaible e open do plugin em questão

Ficaria algo assim:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  if(window.cordova){
    sendMail('teste', "fulano@maluco.com", "E aí fulano maluco, continua insano?");
  }
}, false);
function sendMail(assunto, paraQuem, corpoDoEmail){
    cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
    function (isAvailable) {
        if(!isAvailable){
            return window.alert("Nao pode enviar email");
        }
        cordova.plugins.email.open({
            to:      paraQuem,
            subject: assunto,
            body:    corpoDoEmail
        });
    }
    );
}
```

Essa parte do `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" />` é inserida automaticamente com o comando cordova plugin add que eu citei acima. Se você quiser abrir um draft em branco, sem os dados preenchidos, basta chamar o open sem passar nenhum parâmetro:

```
cordova.plugins.email.open();
```

Comment: pergunta, eu instalo o cordova na pasta www, ou na pasta antes dela?
outra pergunta, onde verifico pra ver se realmente o cordova foi instalando, porque pelo menos, a pasta plugins apareceu aqui

Comment: apareceu, cordova is not defined

Comment: o seu cordova já está instalado, o phonegap é instalado por ele. Pode executar o camando de qualquer lugar do seu projeto. Tem que utilizar o if (window.cordova). O cordova só vai estar definido depois que você fizer o build para smartphone, não dá para usar os plugins do cordova no browser. (Alterei o código)

Comment: utilizando o phonegap no celular e baixando o projeto eu consigo ver se o email abre?

Comment: utilizando phonegap, ele só entra no if do window.cordova.<br /> nos outros ifs, creio eu que só entrará, se buildar.

Comment: Sim, se buildar funcionará corretamente.

Comment: eu instalo o plugin via cmd, mas aquela linha sobre o plugin não aparece no xml, então quando buildo ele não instala esse plugin.

Comment: Estranho. E se você adicionar a linha no xml, funciona corretamente?